# Different image margins on different pages CSS

Tags: images

I am working on my webpage, where I have several descriptions of beers. Two examples are these two:
http://www.xn--l-klubben-k8a.dk/beers/trappistes-rochefort-10/ and
http://www.xn--l-klubben-k8a.dk/beers/esrum-kloster-oel/

My goal is to get all of the text aligned so that the text does not wrap around the image. But since there are different amounts of text on the different pages (as is the case with the two links) I cannot set a fixed margin-bottom after the images, which would work with just one picture.

Is there a way to do this, so I do not have to depend on different image sizes and different amounts of text? And is it possible with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to recode your CSS a little.

Since you have your beer image in its own container that helps.

But you'd want to adjust the CSS:

```
.beer-description{
   float: left;
   width: 70%;
  }
```

You can tweak it as needed.

To not worry about the image size, you should have a width set (can be a percentage) on the `beer-image` container and then 100% width on the `.beer-image img`